# How can I move the content from a 32bit register to a 64 one?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

(Assembly x86)
Basically what I have to do is receive 2 Integers and put them into 32 bit registers, for example, I'm using EAX and EBX, then I add them and the result goes to EAX. The problem is, the result needs to be returned in a 64bit register. how can I combine 2 32bit registers?

My code so far:

```
.section .data

.section .text

.global a
.global b
.global resultado

.global funcao 
 funcao:


    movl $0, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx

    movl a, %eax

    movl b, %ebx

    add %ebx, %eax

   ret
```

As you can see, when I add, the result of the sum goes to %eax but I need to move it to a 64bit register and then move it to the variable "resultado"

Comment: You can store the lowest 32bits to [resultado] and the highest 32 bits to [resultado + 4]. Recalling of course, that Intel stuff is little-endian (least significant part of a number goes into lower memory addresses than the most significant part)

Comment: how would that look coded @enhzflep

Comment: Can you use x64 assembly?

Comment: @Synaps , no, I'm sorry, I'm using x86

Comment: You can try to write them to 2 seial memory cells and then copy this memory area to the place you need.

Comment: @Synaps , yeah, I understand that, but I'm still learning and It's the first problem of this kind that I've faced. Would help a lot if you could help out with some code.

Comment: @PedroGonçalves - I'll leave it up to you to deal with signed integers and capturing the Carry Flag from the addition, which you'll need to use to set bit #32 (0 based). After this is done, it's just like I wrote already. Assuming EAX holds the highest 32 bits and EBX holds the lowest 32 (total arbitrary choice of registers, by the way), it's simply `mov [resultado], ebx` followed by `mov [resultado+4], eax`. Just do a calculation on paper first and then do the same one in code, watching for the expected bit-patterns and the setting if applicable of the Carry flag.

Comment: @enhzflep Alright, that helped a lot, thanks so much!

Comment: @enhzflep Okay, bear with me in this one. I understood what you said and I've solved the problem, but, I have a doubt. The result is on the variable [resultado] and I move it to 2 separated registers as you said using the lowest and highest 32 bits. But the problem is that I don't think I'm returning the value in 64 bits, I just moved the result to 2 different registers without returning them. Is that a safe assumption or not?

Comment: Well, a 16bit mul causes the result to be a 32bit one. It's returned in DX:AX. I don't see the difference (from that perspective) between that situation and your own. Similarly, there's a 64bit value in memory if you stored the contents of the two registers. Whether or not you can read and manipulate all 64 bits at once doesn't really matter, actually it's immaterial. Though, as for returning the answer "in a 64bit register", you can't access the 64 extensions to the general regs in 32 bit mode. You could be sneaky, and return the result in an fpu register, which are actually 80bits wide. ;)

Comment: @enhzflep Okay, thanks a lot, can't thank you enough. I have no further questions. thanks again and have a good day :)